# C++ Calculator Program

Tags: c++, vector

I'm pretty knew to C++. I'm writing a calculator primarily based upon vectors. I want to have that there is a vector for each operation, and if one of the following operations is called, the value will manipulated by the associated vector.
Questions
 1. Is my process correct? Am I on the right track?
 2. Do I need an alternative method for inputting and checking for a char and an int?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

vector <int> addition;
vector <int> subtraction;
vector <int> division;
vector <int> multiplication;

char operation;
int input;

int main() {

    cout << "Welcome to my Calculator Program" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your calculation: ";
    void operation();

    return 0;

}

void operation() {
    cin >> operation;
    switch (operation) {
    case '+':
        addition.push_back(input);
        break;
    case '-':
        subtraction.push_back(input);
        break;
    case '/':
        division.push_back(input);
        break;
    case '*':
        multiplication.push_back(input);
        break;
    default:
        cout << "You have entered an invalid operation" << endl;
    }
}

int add(vector <int> addition) {
    for (int i; i > addition.size(); i++) {
        int sum = std::accumulate(addition.begin(), addition.end(), 0);
    }
    return sum;
}

int sub(vector <int> subtraction) {
    for (int i; i > subtraction.size(); i++) {

    }
}
```

Comment: `void operation();` does not call any function. Instead, it declares a function - and nothing happens at all. I think, you need to get back to books.

Comment: `for (int i; i > subtraction.size(); i++)` - `i` here is not given a value and could be anything. Make sure to initialized to a value!

Comment: `char operation;` and `void operation()` - use different names

Comment: Finally, you never initialize or read into `input`, so `.push_back(input)` is putting an undefined value into your vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right track to me. To answer your second question, no, `cin>>variable;` automatically attempts to convert user input to the type of `variable`.

The main problem with this program is that it will not follow order of operations, which makes it pretty useless as a calculator.

You aren't *calling* `operation()` when you do `void operation();`; you're declaring it. Nothing will happen except a compiler warning.

The whole idea of std::accumulate() is to avoid looping through a vector or array! Reevaluate if you really need those for loops.

Fix your indentation. The way it is now makes it hard to understand the program's flow. Check out: https://www.cs.northwestern.edu/academics/courses/211/html/c++-style.html#indent

Don't use global variables when you can avoid it, which you definitely can in this case. In this program, it doesn't matter, but it's a really bad habit.

You are `using namespace std` but still referring to things as `std::whatever`. That's redundant.

I think you should go back to the textbook and work through some simpler examples. Your logic is (mostly) sound, but you lack a grasp of the syntax. That's nothing to be ashamed of -- C++ is hard and, as you say, you're new -- but you really need to understand that before working on anything more complex than basic examples.

Good luck!

Comment: "It looks like you're on the right track _[except for all the following things you're doing wrong]_". Sure, they might be on the right track _conceptually_, but the understanding of the language really needs work.

Comment: ...However, as you say, this is no problem, as it happens to most of us at this stage in learning. I certainly think the OP is off to a better start than many other new C++ learners I've seen around!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Just to confirm, I will only read one cin to collect both data types, right? I could probably manipulate the arrays via the stack as well to add order of operations.    operation() is kind of pointless. I am kind of pressed for time, as this is due tomorrow. How would I get the add function to execute? I have been unable to do that thus far. Also, is there something similar to accumulate for other operations? Thanks

Comment: You need one `cin>>` operation for _each_ datatype. Honestly I would just use a while loop: make a vector of operations (which is where you'd set up order of operations) and run a loop that while there is still an operation to do, do it, and move on to the next one.

Also, if my answer is what you needed to know, could you accept it so I can get points? Thanks :)